# Enter Input to sublime text

Tags: sublimetext2

I am using sublime text 2 as the editor for my programs and using this code

```
 { "cmd": ["g++", "$file", "-o", "$file_base_name"],
 "selector": "source.c++", "working_dir": "$file_path",
 "variants": [ { "name": "Run", "cmd": ["g++", "$file", "-o", "$file_base_name", "&&", "$file_path/$file_base_name"], "shell": true } ]
}
```

I am able to run the c++ programs but unable to use test inputs in it.
How do I do that...

P.S. I don't wanna take inputs from any file but give to the console itself.

Comment: The console in Sublime Text (both versions 2 and 3) doesn't connect to the standard input of your running program. In order to do this you need your build system to run your program in an external terminal window, or do so manually.

Comment: @OdatNurd Then how do I open it in external terminal window?

Comment: How you would go about that depends on the operating system that you're using.

Comment: I'm using windows 10 64-bit

Comment: You can try adding `"start", "/wait"` to your command in between `"&&"` and `"$file_path/$file_base_name"` to get windows to launch it in its own window (caveat: I don't use Win10 so the command may or may not be slightly different there). You may need to modify your program to wait for a key press before it exits to stop the window from vanishing as soon as it's done, though.